# Thread-safe log buffer in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing my own logging system for performance purposes (and because i basically just need a buffer). What i currently have is something like this:

```
// category => messages
static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::ostringstream> log;

void main() {
    while (true) {
        log["info"] << "Whatever";
        log["192.168.0.1"] << "This is a dynamic entry";

        dump_logs();
    }
}

void dump_logs() {
    // i do something like this for each category, but they have different save strategies
    if (log["info"].tellp() > 1000000) {
        // save the ostringstream to a file

        // clear the log
        log["info"].str("")
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. However, i've just added threads and i'm not sure if this code is thread-safe. Any tips?

Comment: What do you by you "just need a buffer"? Doing a map lookup every log call doesn't seem very efficient to me. And no, it's not threadsafe. The map lookups aren't threadsafe and the ostringstream writes aren't threadsafe.

Comment: That code is not thread safe. If you're interested in what a thread safe logging system might look like, I've got a custom one I made in my profile that you are free to use and manipulate as you wish.

Comment: I need categories in order to separate the buffer offload strategy. And the categories are dynamic. That's why i need the map lookup.

Comment: You can use a mutex whenever you do something with the log to ensure logs dont get used with more than 1 threads at a time. Even making a class so you dont have to create a mutex every time would be better.

Comment: This is not a logging library. Is a very specific solution to a very specific problem. I'm not trying to outperform anyone and i really don't understand the attitude here.

Comment: Striker, what if instead of declaring the buffer as static, i declare it inside my thread function? This way, each thread has it's own buffer.

Comment: You can use `thread_local static` to create a buffer for each thread. You still need to synchronize writing it out to disk. I doubt if accessing a map is going to slow you down much compared to writing to disk. But you could still use a disk based logger that has a super large buffer.

Comment: Would i be better off with something like this to handle the buffer? https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue

Comment: @SergeyA No he isn't. Not in context of what he's replying to. He's not doing a full blown logging library and he doesn't want to drag one into his project with its dependency etc. He just wants a simple fast thread-safe solution. its not a crime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this thread safe by declaring your *map* `thread_local`. If you are going to use it across *translation units* then make it `extern` and define it in *one* *translation unit*, otherwise `static` is fine.

You will still need to synchronize writing the logs to disk. A *mutex* should fix that:

```
// category => messages (one per thread)
thread_local static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::ostringstream> log;

void main() {
    while (true) {
        log["info"] << "Whatever";
        log["192.168.0.1"] << "This is a dynamic entry";

        dump_logs();
    }
}

void dump_logs() {

    static std::mutex mtx; // mutex shared between threads

    // i do something like this for each category, but they have different save strategies
    if (log["info"].tellp() > 1000000) {

        // now I need to care about threads
        // use { to create a lock that will release at the end }
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // synchronized access

            // save the ostringstream to a file
        }

        // clear the log
        log["info"].str("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a quick question, that is somewhat related, and since you helped me a lot, you probably know the answer for this one too! How can i tackle the issue of buffer remainders? If there are less than 1000000 bytes left in the log, they'll not be saved. I just realized this. :(

Comment: @vinnylinux Well you could have a similar function called `close_logs()` that does the same thing without the check so it always empties the buffers. Or you could wrap the whole thing up in a class and do something in the destructor.

Comment: Yes, but i'm in a while true loop, because this is a daemon. What first came to my mind was a thread dedicated to run in periods, like a cron, to offload the buffers.

Comment: @vinnylinux Without knowing the whole situation its hard to come up with ideas. I presume you want to save the logs when the daemon is shut down/restarted? What about trapping the kill signal?

Comment: Not really. I just found out that saving the logs (some go to disk, others to MySQL, others sent via webhook, etc) was becoming expensive, so i decided to make a buffer and send them in big chunks.

Comment: Just so you, this is a game server. That's why it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks for the attention :D

Answer (score 1):

On a POSIX system, if you're always writing data to the end of the file, the fastest way for multiple threads to write data to a file is to use low-level C-style `open()` in append mode, and just call `write()`, because the [POSIX standard for `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) states:

> On a regular file or other file capable of seeking, the actual writing
>   of data shall proceed from the position in the file indicated by the
>   file offset associated with fildes. Before successful return from
>   write(), the file offset shall be incremented by the number of bytes
>   actually written. On a regular file, if the position of the last byte
>   written is greater than or equal to the length of the file, the length
>   of the file shall be set to this position plus one.
>
> ...
>
> If the O_APPEND flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset
>   shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no
>   intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing
>   the file offset and the write operation.

So, all `write()` calls from within a process to a file opened in append mode are atomic.

No mutexes are needed.

Almost.  The only issue you have to be concerned with is

> If `write()` is interrupted by a signal after it successfully writes
>   some data, it shall return the number of bytes written.

If you have enough control over your environment that you can be sure that your calls to `write()` will not be interrupted by a signal after only a portion of the data is written, this is the fastest way to write data to a file from multiple threads - you're using the OS-provided lock on the file descriptor that ensures adherence to the POSIX-specified behavior, and as long as you generate the data to be written without any locking, that file descriptor lock is the only one in the entire data path.  And that lock will be in your data path no matter what you do in your code.